# Unable to fill list with content of a file

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<string> file1 = new List<string>();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the path to the folder");
            string path1 = Console.ReadLine();

            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path1);
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to put the content of the file (text) into the list. I tried to look on this website for help but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried to get the text into the list? Also, please format the question correctly so that it is easier to read.

Comment: Your (had) problems with grammar in your title, in future please provide more efforts to compose your questions, otherwise people will be down-voting your question and it won't get necessary attention and you won't get appropriate answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to have a list of each line use `File.ReadAllLines`.

```
List<string> file1 = new List<string>();

Console.WriteLine("Enter the path to the folder");
string path1 = Console.ReadLine();

file1.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path1));

foreach(var line in file1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't display it now. What i did is Console.WriteLine("{0}, file1); do i have to do it differently ?

Comment: You can iterate through the list with a foreach loop. I will edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine!

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> file1 = new List<string>();

        Console.Write("Enter the path to the folder:");
        string path1 = Console.ReadLine();

        file1.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path1));

        foreach(var line in file1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this if you like lambda.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> file1 = new List<string>();

        Console.Write("Enter the path to the folder:");
        string path1 = Console.ReadLine();

        file1.AddRange(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path1));

        file1.ForEach(line => Console.WriteLine(line));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```